# Terms aggregation failing on string fields with a custom analyzer in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, aggregation, analyzer

I want a custom analyzer that behaves exactly like `not_analyzed` but case insensitive.

My current custom analyzer is

```
"index": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": { // Custom Analyzer with keyword tokenizer and lowercase filter, same as not_analyzed but case insensitive
            "case_insensitive_keyword_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": "lowercase"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I'm trying to do terms aggregation over a particular string with this custom analyzer, I'm getting this exception.

```
{
   "error" :"ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.DoubleTerms$Bucket cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.terms.StringTerms$Bucket]",
   "status" : 500
}
```

This is my aggregation query:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "unique-category-ids": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "categoryid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simply put, all I need is a custom analyzer that behaves exactly like `not_analyzed` except that it is case insensitive.

EDIT: I had these settings in an index template, and I used dynamic templates to make every string field take my custom analyzer..

What I didn't realize was I'm doing terms aggregation on a field that was mapped `double`. So that's the reason for that error.

But what I don't understand is why Elasticsearch didn't throw an error when I'm indexing `strings` into a field that was mapped `double`. Very weird.

Comment: Did you apply your analyzer to your mapping?

Comment: Please share the complete mapping (or at least the properties of field `categoryid`) of the index.

Comment: Could you post the settings of your index (actually only the analysis part) and the mapping of the type on which you wish to calculate the aggregations?

Comment: I had it in my index template.. and used dynamic mapping to map all string fields with my custom analyzer..

Comment: https://gist.github.com/syllogismos/c2dde4f097fea149e1a0 here is my index template..

Comment: My mistake guys, my field is actually mapped as double.. I don't understand.. :O How can it be mapped to `double` when I see strings when I search for sample documents..

Comment: `home-kitchen-curtains-blinds` this value is mapped as double? I'm seeing things :O

Comment: How can a field that is mapped `double` accept `string` without throwing me an error while indexing?